# Where to specify the repository element for Artifactory release?

Tags: maven, pom.xml, artifactory, maven-release-plugin

I am trying to release a project in the Artifactory repository. It’s a project which is a dependency of my main project, so I would like to put the pom, the .jar and the sources.jar in the artifactory repository.

The settings.xml file is stored in the maven directory :

```
D:\...\...\maven\apache-maven-3.3.1\conf
```

I have already tagged the version using following maven command :

```
mvn clean release:prepare
```

Then, if I try :

```
mvn clean release:perform –Partifactory
```

, I get the error :

> [INFO] [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project ........ : Deployment failed: repository element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement element or in -DaltDeploymentRepository=id::layout::url parameter

What should I do to use the artifactory profile ? Is it possible without changing the pom ?
I have tried without success to copy the settings.xml in my local maven repository.

If I have to change the pom, can I first come back before the state obtained after the mvn release:prepare command ? In the following link, I didn’t understand if I have to do something manually or not (remove tag from the SCM) :
http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/rollback-release.html

The settings.xml file :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

<localRepository>D:\...\...\maven\repository</localRepository>

<profiles>  
<profile>  
  <repositories>  
    <repository>  
      <snapshots>  
        <enabled>false</enabled>  
      </snapshots>  
      <id>central</id>  
      <name>libs-release</name>  
      <url>http://x/artifactory/libs-release</url>  
    </repository>  
    <repository>  
      <snapshots />  
      <id>snapshots</id>  
      <name>libs-snapshot</name>  
      <url>http://x/artifactory/libs-snapshot</url>  
    </repository>  
  </repositories>  
  <pluginRepositories>  
    <pluginRepository>  
      <snapshots>  
        <enabled>false</enabled>  
      </snapshots>  
      <id>central</id>  
      <name>plugins-release</name>  
      <url>http://x/artifactory/plugins-release</url>  
    </pluginRepository>  
    <pluginRepository>  
      <snapshots />  
      <id>snapshots</id>  
      <name>plugins-snapshot</name>  
      <url>http://x/artifactory/plugins-snapshot</url>  
    </pluginRepository>  
  </pluginRepositories>  
  <id>artifactory</id>  
</profile>  
  </profiles>  
  <activeProfiles>  
   <activeProfile>artifactory</activeProfile>  
  </activeProfiles>  

</settings>
```

The pom :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <parent>
        <groupId>....</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.6</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>....</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.9.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>myproject</name>
    <url>${wiki.url}</url>
    <scm>    <developerConnection>scm:svn:http://x/svn/main/y/Development/Components/trunk/myproject</developerConnection>
        <url>http://x/svn/main/y/Development/Components/trunk/myproject</url>
    </scm>
    <ciManagement>
        <system>${ciManagement.system}</system>
        <url>${ciManagement.url}/${project.artifactId}</url>        
    </ciManagement>

    <properties>       
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <! -  - my dependencies -  - >
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <inherited>false</inherited>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <configuration>   <tagBase>http://x/svn/main/y/Development/Components/tags</tagBase>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    </project>

The parent pom :  

<!-- language: lang-xml -->

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>....</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-parent</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0.6</version>
    <name>my-parent</name>
    <url>${wiki.url}</url>
    <scm>
        <developerConnection>scm:svn:http://x/svn/main/y/Development/Components/tags/my-parent-1.0.6</developerConnection>
        <url>http://x/svn/main/y/Development/Components/tags/my-parent-1.0.6</url>
    </scm>
    <ciManagement>
        <system>${ciManagement.system}</system>
        <url>${ciManagement.url}/${project.artifactId}</url>        
    </ciManagement>
    <build> 
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things. You should declare a `<distributionManagement>` section in your POM:

```
<project>
  ...
  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
     <id>my-artifactory</id>
     <name>Artifactory Release Repo</name>
     <url>http://x/artifactory/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
     <id>my-artifactory</id>
     <name>Artifactory Release Repo</name>
     <url>http://x/artifactory/libs-snapshot</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
  </distributionManagement>
</project>
```

The `<id>` tags must match an entry in your `settings.xml` for the credentials to match:

```
<settings>
  ...
  <servers>
   <server>
    <id>my-artifactory</id>
    <username>bob</username>
    <password>secret</password>
   </server>
  </servers>
</settings>
```

Now, that being said, since `mvn release:prepare` has already tagged the release in your VCS, you don't *need* to cut a new release, but I would advise you to add the `<distributionManagement>` section to the POM. One way to deploy the artifacts is to simply get the tag from the VCS and do an `mvn deploy`, like so:

```
svn co <the url to your tag>
mvn -DaltDeploymentRepository=my-artifactory::default::http://x/artifactory/libs-release deploy
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I don't understand the difference beetween mvn deploy and mvn release:perform. Do they both copy the project to the remote repository ? Does one of them make something more ? Second question : what is the use of repositories informations in the settings.xml if they are already present in the pom ?

Comment: Well, `mvn deploy` does **only** that: deploys the artifacts. `release:perform` picks up where `release:prepare` left off. By using the information in the `release.properties` files from the `release:prepare` stage, `release:perform` will actually, depending on your set-up, do a checkout from the tag created during `release:prepare` and a `deploy`.

Comment: So, both commands deploy all artifacts (pom, sources.jar, jar, javadoc.jar, war) if they are defined in the pom ?

Comment: Yes, but the `release` plugin will transform the POMs, tag, commit, push (for git), etc. Also, both need the `<distributionManagement>` section to deploy.

Comment: I tried with your recommanded changes : Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project myproject: Failed to retrieve remote metadata ...:myproject:1.9.6-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml: Could not transfer metadata...: myproject:1.9.6-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to my-artifactory (http://x/artifactory/libs-release): Failed to transfer file: http://x/artifactory/libs-release/... / myproject /1.9.6-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml. Return code is: 502 , ReasonPhrase:Proxy Error. Do you think it is a problem of user/password for artifactory ?

Comment: It seems that you are trying to deploy a snapshot to a release repository. I am also puzzled by the 502. Is your Artifactory hiding behind a reverse proxy?

Comment: I executed the mvn command from the wrong directory (one that contains the pom with snapshot). Moreover I specified virtual directories for url of repositories (libs-release instead of libs-release-local). Now, I get an new error : Return code is: 401, ReasonPhrase: User anonymous is not permitted to deploy.

Comment: Ok, this is good. You are making progress. Did you out your credentials in `settings.xml`? They are supposed to be in `<USER HOME>/.m2/settings.xml`.

Comment: they are in the local maven repository (we don't use .m2)

Comment: Ok, it doesn't really matter from a functionality perspective. If you do a `mvn help:effective-settings`, does it show your credentials? If they do (and they are correct) you have to start looking in Artifactory's logs/settings. If they don't, then Maven is not picking up the same `settings.xml` you are editing; this might suggest different Maven installations. Is your user named `anonymous`?

Comment: I can not use maven-help-plugin, even after manually adding the plugin in the local maven repository. Still a proxy error (we can no longer authenticate on artifactory and jenkins since some time : proxy error too). That's why I thought to give user anonymous permission to deploy on artifactory (it's not a named user), but I don't know how to do without being authentified in artifactory.

Comment: Here errors : Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (http://x/artifactory/plugins-release-local): Failed to transfer file: http://x/artifactory/plugins-release-local/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-help-plugin/maven-metadata.xml. Return code is: 502 , ReasonPhrase:Proxy Error.

Comment: This is out of scope as far as Maven is concerned. You need to involve the people responsible for the proxy at your organization.